# Odoo 11.0 modules: Missing dependencies: (2) ["web.form_relational", "web.form_common"]

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I'm using the [`project_team`](https://github.com/JayVora-SerpentCS/SerpentCS_Contributions/) module for my instance, and I'm getting this warning in the browser console: `Non loaded modules: ["project_team.form_rel"]`.

Searching deep in the module i found that the origin of this problem in this: `Missing dependencies: (2) ["web.form_relational", "web.form_common"]`
[image: issue]

I could see that those modules are present in `odoo` [10.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/10.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views) and it's not in 11.0.

I think it requires an update, but i cannot find any information about how can we replace this two old modules in the new `odoo` version.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So I am assuming you are using Odoo 11. Why not use [project_team for version 11](https://github.com/JayVora-SerpentCS/SerpentCS_Contributions/tree/11.0/project_team)? You linked to version 10. You should enable debug logging in your config file. I usually see such error logs in the console

Comment: I'm using `project_team` for 11.0 of course.

Comment: Actually, i linked that module because it shows my point: that modules are present in the 10.0 version but not in 11.0 version; i want to know how can we solve that issue for 11.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sad answer, but IMHO it's the right one: if the module needs fixing, you have to fix it.

From Odoo 10 to 11, almost all the JS was refactored, so many JS add-ons don't work out of the box when migrating them. You have to dig through the code to search where are those features you need, and patch the add-on. A good place to start searching is the [addons/web/static/src/js](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js) folder. [The JS reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/javascript_reference.html) might help you too.

Another thing that should help is running Odoo in development mode with assets (append `?debug=assets` to the URL), which should also log in the console the reasons a given JS module hasn't been loaded, and loads the unminified sources to allow easier debugging.

Finally, if you can provide good logs and a good reproducible case, there are chances that if you publish an issue in the corresponding github project, maintainers help you.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: I published an issue, they still don't answer it.

Comment: That sort of things can happen. If you didn't pay, you can't expect enterprise support. And if you did, you should request it. Another option is to fix it yourself and open a pull request, which is usually better received.

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how can i solve it, i could not find another example to base a new pull request. That's why i did this question.